# How should I handle ClaimsPrincipal in unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a controller that checks the claims to get the current user's username, role, like so:

```
var identity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
bUsername = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "Username").Value;
role = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "Role").Value;
```

These details are set when the user first logs in.  When I try to test this method, if falls over at the lines of code above because there was no login.  So I tried creating a principal in the TestInitialization so it would always be available for the controllers asking for the username in the above way:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Test Name"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "test"),
    new Claim("Username", "test"),
    new Claim("Role","ADMIN")
};
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TestAuthType");
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
```

I breakpointed the code, and it hits this code before it hits the above code, so it seems like it is creating the principal before checking for the username, however it still falls over on the username check, it's still not finding anything.

Can anybody advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Nkosi The claims are assigned when the user first logs in, then they are accessible by any of the other controllers.  I'm testing a single method which means there is no login, so it's never set.  I'm wanting to set it manually so when the controller checks for the claims, they are there.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do it like this at all. I would inject a class that does the claims stuff internally, that way you can mock it out easily.

Comment: @DavidG  This is my first time using claims, I don't know how else to do it.  When the user logs in, the claims are set up, then I use a base controller that does the check for the username and role, so these variables are then accessible by any instantiated controller.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that you should abstract the claims code into its own class that you inject into the controller. That way, when you unit test, you inject a mock object instead.

Comment: @Nkosi That code is called in a base controller constructor, which all other controllers inherit, so any time a controller is instantiated it will have access to those variables.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 you should take some time and review [Migrate from ClaimsPrincipal.Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @DavidG  I will attempt to implement what you are saying.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, I will take a look at that.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 tightly coupling to static implementation concerns makes testing your code in isolation very difficult and is usually ill advised.

Comment: @Nkosi I will try to remember this.  I just started looking into unit of work, IoC, dependency injection, and I'm starting to see this logic.  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG Put an answer in for using injection to mock the class, this is what I tried and it worked.  Thank you and Nkosi for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on the advice of @DavidG, I ended up abstracting the claim stuff out of the controller.  Posting this here for anyone else that needs help in the future.  I created the following classes:

**ICurrentUser**

```
public interface ICurrentUser
{
    User GetUserDetails();
}
```

**CurrentUser**

```
public class CurrentUser : ICurrentUser
{
    public User GetUserDetails()
    {
        var user = new User();
        try
        {
            var identity = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
            user.Username = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "Username").Value;
            user.Role = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "Role").Value;
            user.LoggedIn = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "LoggedIn").Value;

            return user;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added it to my constructor like so:

```
public readonly ICurrentUser currentUser;
public readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ICurrentUser currentUser)
{
    this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
}
```

Then I use Ninject to inject it:

```
kernel.Bind<ICurrentUser>().To<CurrentUser>().InRequestScope();
```

Now it is loosely coupled to my controller, allowing me to mock it, like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _unitOfWorkMock;
    private Mock<ICurrentUser> _currentUserMock;
    private HomeController _objController;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        _currentUserMock = new Mock<ICurrentUser>();
        _currentUserMock.Setup(x => x.GetUserDetails()).Returns(new User { Username = "TEST", Role = "ADMIN", LoggedIn = "Y" });
        _objController = new HomeController(_unitOfWorkMock.Object, _currentUserMock.Object);
    }
}
```